# Play video from url in default android player

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
    mContext.startActivity(i);
```

The code above opens the default web browser to show the video. How could I make it open the default video player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way, as "the default video player" varies by device, and there is no guarantee that it can handle your request.

To help, you can add the MIME type, by using `setDataAndType()` instead of `setData()`.

Comment: Yes! that is what I needed. We can't guarantee which default player etc... but at least it looks for it instead of the web browser.